# How to manually deploy artifacts in Nexus Repository Manager OSS 3

Tags: repository, nexus, artifacts, nexus3

After installing Nexus Repository Manager OSS 3 I do not see option `Artifact Upload` to upload artifacts through web page.

In Nexus Repository Manager OSS 2.13 there is option to do that operation.

Anyone can show me the way how to upload artifacts to hosted repository in Nexus 3?

**EDIT**: *From 3.9.0 version, this functionality is implemented.*

Comment: In my answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40130685/2614103) I explained both approaches - for http and https.

Comment: why on earth would they leave out this essential piece of functionality?

Comment: Since the upload GUI still not part of Nexus 3, we have created a lightweight solution to provide the missing interface. You can host a html page in a raw repository of your Nexus3 instance, and when you access that page from the browser, it will provide an upload GUI similar to the one in Nexus2. The project can be found on [GitHub](https://github.com/TOPdesk/nexus3-artifact-upload) with detailed documentation. The released version at the time of this answer supports GAV style and raw uploads as well.

Comment: Official documentation at this time : https://help.sonatype.com/repomanager3/using-nexus-repository/uploading-components

Answer (score 32, accepted):

This is implemented in Nexus since Version 3.9.0.

- Login
- Select Upload

[image]

- Fill out form and upload Artifact

[image]

Comment: We had 3.7 installed and the feature matrix was saying this should exist (3.10 is now current). I was going mad trying to figure out how it was implemented. This answer was very helpful. I'd up vote you 10 times if I could.

Comment: Bower (hosted) repositories don't have upload feature :/

Comment: @tobias what's the typical value for extension?

Comment: @Varun Verma filename extension e.g. jar

Comment: And in case you still don't see the "Upload" button: you need to assign the `nx-component-upload`  privilege to the user. (see Sonatype Documentation: [Uploading Components](https://help.sonatype.com/repomanager3/using-nexus-repository/uploading-components)).

Answer (score 90):

I'm using maven deploy file.

```
mvn deploy:deploy-file -DgroupId=my.group.id \
    -DartifactId=my-artifact-id \
    -Dversion=1.0.0.1 \
    -Dpackaging=jar \
    -Dfile=foo.jar \
    -DgeneratePom=true \
    -DrepositoryId=my-repo \
    -Durl=http://my-nexus-server.com:8081/repository/maven-releases/
```

UPDATE:
*As stated in comments using quotes in url cause NoSuchElementException*
But I have add server config in my maven (~/.m2/settings.xml).

```
<servers>
  <server>
    <id>my-repo</id>
    <username>admin</username>
    <password>admin123</password>
  </server>
</servers>
```

References:

[Maven Apache - Guide 3rd party jars](https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-3rd-party-jars-remote.html)

Comment: Do I have to enable or install anything to deploy like that? I get following errors when I try :

Nov 29, 2016 11:27:31 AM org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.httpclient.impl.execchain.RetryExec execute
INFO: I/O exception (java.net.SocketException) caught when processing request to {}->http://127.0.0.1:8081: Broken pipe 

and so on...

Comment: No. ONly pure maven. Do you have proxy? Maybe you need to ignore localhost / 127.0.0.1 there / or this ip and port are correct? I'llnsearch other sugestion to solve this eception.

Comment: I think the problem is that I am using Nexus 3, not Nexus 2.

Comment: @ErayTuncer In my example i have validated using nexus 3. Could you past full stack trace?

Comment: Using Maven 3.3.9, I'm getting the following error:

 Cannot access '[http://XXX/repository/XXX](http://XXX/repository/XXX/)' with type default using the available connector factories: BasicRepositoryConnectorFactory: Can not access '[http://XXX/repository/XXX](http://XXX/repository/XXX/)' using the registered transporter factories: WagonTransporterFactory: java.util.NoSuchElementException

Comment: To get rid of the NoSuchElementException: remove the quotes from the -Durl switch's value. Took me 2 hours of search.

Comment: @bpedroso how I upload 3rd pom's without jars?

Comment: do not forget to wrap this "servers" snippet into  "<settings></settings>" element if you are creating a new settings.xml file. otherwise this section will be silently ignored.

Answer (score 43):

This isn't currently implemented in the UI in Nexus 3 (see https://issues.sonatype.org/browse/NEXUS-10121).
You'll need to use `curl` or `mvn deploy` or some other option.

Comment: As time goes by this is turning out to be a MASSIVE PITA.

Answer (score 30):

You can upload artifacts via their native publishing capabilities (e.g. maven deploy, npm publish).

You can also upload artifacts to "raw" repositories via a simple curl request, e.g.

```
curl --fail -u admin:admin123 --upload-file foo.jar 'http://my-nexus-server.com:8081/repository/my-raw-repo/'
```

Comment: Yes i can do this by `mvn deploy` and it works perfectly but i did not realize that they removed `Artifact Upload` option from latest `Nexus`.

Comment: @PawełGłowacz the Jira issue for the upload functionality in 3.x is here: https://issues.sonatype.org/browse/NEXUS-10121

Comment: Read curl's man file about the --fail switch - its not fail-safe

Answer (score 3):

My Team built a command line tool for uploading artifacts to nexus 3.x repository, Maybe it's will be helpful for you - [Maven Artifacts Uploader](https://github.com/ronbadur/maven-artifacts-uploader)

Comment: But only for Windows users?

Comment: At this moment, yes

Answer (score 2):

To use mvn deploy:deploy-file, must add ~./m2/settings.xml

```
<settings>
  <servers>
    <server>
      <id>nexus-repo</id>
      <username>admin</username>
      <password>admin123</password>
    </server>
  </servers>
</settings>
```

command:

```
mvn deploy:deploy-file -DgroupId=com.example \
                                       -DartifactId=my-app \
                                       -Dversion=2.0.0 \
                                       -Dpackaging=jar \
                                       -Dfile=my-app.jar \
                                       -DgeneratePom=true \
                                       -DrepositoryId=nexus-repo \
                                       -Durl=http://localhost:8081/repository/maven-releases/
```

Answer (score 1):

My team use **Gradle** and **Nexus OSS 3.5.2**,

I have found a  *solution*: upload artyfacts from *localhost* (I checked Nexus documentation and did not found anything about uploading artifacts from folders) **=>** I have shared directory (use **Apache httpd**) and connected one to created new Nexus proxy repository. Now when I want to **add** my own **artifacts** I can upload ones into shared directory in my remote server.

Maybe someone find my solution useful:
[image]

**My question is here**: [Is it possible to deploy artifacts from local folder in Sonatype Nexus Repository Manager 3.x](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48294941/is-it-possible-to-deploy-artifacts-from-local-folder-in-sonatype-nexus-repositor)

Answer (score 1):

For Windows:

```
mvn deploy:deploy-file -DgroupId=joda-time -DartifactId=joda-time -Dversion=2.7 -Dpackaging=jar -Dfile=joda-time-2.7.jar 
-DgeneratePom=true -DrepositoryId=[Your ID] -Durl=[YourURL]
```