# Upload JAR to Nexus OSS 3

Tags: maven, nexus

I have just installed Nexus OSS 3.0.1-01 on my server and I don't know how to upload artifacts to my maven repository. I need to upload JDBC and other dependencies to it, but I cannot find how!

It seems there is no section "Upload artifacts" as Nexus 2.

Comment: There is no feature like in `Nexus 2`. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37543120/how-to-manually-deploy-artifacts-in-nexus-repository-manager-oss-3  From what i see on sonatype forum it will be added in future. For now you need to use `mvn deploy` command for that kind operation.

Comment: We've just created a drop-in solution for the missing upload GUI, so you can try that out. To "install" it, you need to host a html file in a raw repository, and when you open the uploaded html from Nexus3, it will provide a file upload interface, similar the one in Nexus2. It also supports GAV (Maven) style upload. The html file is available at [GitHub](https://github.com/TOPdesk/nexus3-artifact-upload) with detailed documentation.

Comment: If you don't find the GUI, you can use [**curl** command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38593513/how-to-upload-jar-to-nexus-oss-3/46308981#46308981).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to manually deploy artifacts in Nexus Repository Manager OSS 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37543120/how-to-manually-deploy-artifacts-in-nexus-repository-manager-oss-3)