# how to upload JAR to Nexus OSS 3?

Tags: nexus, nexus3

How to perform an upload of a jar via `curl` the Nexus 3?
I tried using the [link tips](https://support.sonatype.com/hc/en-us/articles/213465818-How-can-I-programatically-upload-an-artifact-into-Nexus) but without success.

Here are my attempts:

```
curl -v -F r = -F releases hasPom = true and = -F jar -F file = @. / v12.1.0.1 / pom.xml -F file = @. / v12.1.0.1 / ojdbc7.jar -u admin: admin123 http: // localhost: 8081 / repository / maven releases

curl -v -F r = -F releases hasPom = false -F and -F jar = g = com.oracle.jdbc -F = ojdbc7 -F v = 1.0 p = -F jar -F file = @. / v12 .1.0.1 / ojdbc7.jar -u admin: admin123 http: // localhost: 8081 / repository / maven releases
```

Both have 400 Bad Request.

Comment: Why do you have all that spaces in your parameters?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I've modified your code as below. Please try this.

```
curl -v -F r=releases -F hasPom=false -F e=jar -F g=com.oracle.jdbc -F a=ojdbc7 -F v=1.0 -F p=jar -F file=@"./v12.1.0.1/ojdbc7.jar" -u admin:admin123 http://localhost:8081/nexus/service/local/artifact/maven/content
```

Also I would suggest using the full path rather than relative path. Can you share where you are using this curl snippet? Any CI tool like Jenkins?

Comment: URL "service/local/artifact" is not supported in Nexus v3.

Comment: @grajsek can you confirm if this rest end point has been removed in OSS3? I'll change to the same.

Comment: The path where the file is uploaded has changed when compared to Nexus 2 - now it's `/repository/<repo-id>/<full-path-of-file-including-group-and-version>` e.g. `/repository/snapshots/com/foo/bar/1.0.0-SNAPSHOT/baz-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.pom`. See https://support.sonatype.com/hc/en-us/articles/115006744008-How-can-I-programmatically-upload-an-artifact-into-Nexus-3- for details.

Answer (score 10):

**Contents of directory**

cert_for_nexus.pem

curl.exe

pom.xml

utils-1.0.jar

**Nexus v3 is configured for http**

curl -v -u admin:admin123 --upload-file pom.xml http://localhost:8081/nexus/repository/maven-releases/org/foo/utils/1.0/utils-1.0.pom

curl -v -u admin:admin123 --upload-file utils-1.0.jar http://localhost:8081/nexus/repository/maven-releases/org/foo/utils/1.0/utils-1.0.jar

**Nexus v3 is configured for https**

- prerequisite: must have curl with SSL enabled ([link](http://www.paehl.com/open_source/) - left menu)

curl -v --cacert cert_for_nexus.pem -u admin:admin123 --upload-file pom.xml https://localhost:8443/nexus/repository/maven-releases/org/foo/utils/1.0/utils-1.0.pom

curl -v --cacert cert_for_nexus.pem -u admin:admin123 --upload-file utils-1.0.jar https://localhost:8443/nexus/repository/maven-releases/org/foo/utils/1.0/utils-1.0.jar

**Contents of pom.xml**

```
<project>
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>org.foo</groupId>
  <artifactId>utils</artifactId>
  <version>1</version>
</project>
```

**EDIT:** fixed -u order for both https examples

Answer (score 2):

You could use [nexus-cli](https://github.com/sjeandeaux/nexus-cli).

```
docker run -ti -v $(pwd):$(pwd):ro sjeandeaux/nexus-cli:0.2.0 \
                          -repo=http://nexus:8081/repository/maven-releases \
                          -user=admin \
                          -password=admin123 \
                          -file=$(pwd)/upload.jar \
                          -groupID=your.group \
                          -artifactID=yourArtifactID \
                          -version=0.1.0 \
                          -hash md5 \
                          -hash sha1
```