# Nexus 2 OSS vs. Nexus 3

Tags: nexus, nexus3

I operate some Docker services. Some of them are selfmade with Dockerfiles. I now want to store them into a Sonatype Nexus private repository to publish them to another server in my network.

My research half a year ago gave me Nexus 2 OSS as best option. But now Nexus 3 got released and I'm kinda confused. What version should I use? Greatest confusion is because there is no difference between Pro and OSS version anymore on Docker Hub:

- [sonatype/nexus](https://hub.docker.com/r/sonatype/nexus/tags/) has got tags `oss` and `pro`
- [sonatype/nexus3](https://hub.docker.com/r/sonatype/nexus3/tags/) has only got tags like `3.x.x`

Question is: May I use Nexus 3 for free? Or will there be any costs as in Nexus 2 Pro?

Comment: There are not much changes on Nexus 2 vs 3 from the application level.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Nexus Repository Manager 2 does not support Docker as a format. Nexus Repository Manager 3 does, and Docker support is a part of our OSS solution, meaning you can use Docker completely free. There is a professional version coming with 3.1 that will start to have features such as high availability, expanded enterprise support, as well as just regular support of the product.

As for the Docker images, Nexus 3 now has the ability to operate as OSS or Pro from the same bundle so you'll likely only see tags for Releases, not OSS and Pro.

Comment: Thank you very much for bringing light into the darkness ;)

Comment: for those concerned: file uploading seems to have been implemented since 3.9, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37543120/how-to-manually-deploy-artifacts-in-nexus-repository-manager-oss-3