# Is it possible to deploy artifacts from local folder in Sonatype Nexus Repository Manager 3.x

Tags: dependencies, repository, nexus, artifacts, nexus3

I use *Sonatype Nexus Repository Manager 3.5.2* and want to add **artifacts** to **nexus blob store** from local folder (*where nexus is lockated*). I couldn't find solution in Nexus documentation and tryed to find in the Net - *unsuccessfully*.

Is it possible and how to do this (*maybe Nexus has some plugin*)?

*thx for any help .....*

```
Update: I have found a solution -> see Answers.
```

Comment: See here: http://www.sonatype.org/nexus/2017/09/08/uploading-to-nexus-repository-3/? Basically not possible _yet_, but planned/started.

Comment: @Tom - my question about deploying artifacts from local directory , I saw post: [How to manually deploy artifacts in Nexus Repository Manager OSS 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37543120/how-to-manually-deploy-artifacts-in-nexus-repository-manager-oss-3)

Comment: Then this answer applies well: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39757111/2169091

Comment: Basically, the idea is that there is no additional option for upload if the JAR is already physically on the Nexus host.

Comment: Yes,  **JAR**  is located in a server in some directory and y want to add one to **Nexus**  blob ( and Nexus will cash this file). I don't want to make own http-server and refer Nexus to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a *temporary solution*(I checked Nexus documentation and did not found paragraph about it) **=>** I have shared directory (use **Apache httpd**) and connected one to *created new Nexus proxy repository*. Now when I want to add my own **artifacts** I can upload ones into shared directory in my remote server.

My *temporary solution*: [image]