# How to upload jars to Nexus?

Tags: maven, nexus

In my project, I used some dependencies like springboot, jboss, liquibase and so on. Now I want to upload these jars to my Nexus.
Upload by chosing POM, and succeed.

But in the repositories, it just has .pom, .md5 and .sha1 files, No Jar file.
I had find the answer for about the hole day. Thank you anybody who knows.

Comment: Check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37543120/how-to-manually-deploy-artifacts-in-nexus-repository-manager-oss-3

Comment: Usually those jars will be automatically downloaded from Central via Nexus ...and it shouldn't be necessary to upload them manually...

Comment: Thanks a lot. Because my Nexus is offline in the LAN

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to manually deploy artifacts in Nexus Repository Manager OSS 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37543120/how-to-manually-deploy-artifacts-in-nexus-repository-manager-oss-3)