# How to directly upload a jar file to nexus repository using maven without pom file or settings.xml file?

Tags: maven, nexus

Context : I do not have UI access to Nexus Repository but I have access to Jenkins configured with access to nexus repository. I have a shaded jar in my git repository which needs to be directly uploaded to nexus repository using maven without pom.xml or settings.xml file.

Problem : How to upload a jar in git repo to nexus repository using Jenkins with maven plugin ?

I tried searching for this specific usecase and was not able to find a solution.

Comment: Why no settings.XML? Seems like an odd constraint.  If you don't have pom.XML, well OK, one can be generated using deploy.

Comment: related https://stackoverflow.com/a/39757111/1824361

Answer (score 5):

You can create a Jenkins Job to clone git repository [Source Code Management] where the required jar is present and configure Jenkins Job Build stage with below maven command [Execute Shell] :

```
mvn deploy:deploy-file \
    -DgroupId=com.example.test \
    -DartifactId=test-module \
    -Dversion=1.0.0 \
    -DgeneratePom=true \
    -Dpackaging=jar \
    -DrepositoryId=sample-rel \
    -Durl=http://nexus.private.net/Your_Nexus_Repository_Path \
    -Dfile=./PATH_TO_JAR_FILE
```

(edit: multi-line for legibility)

Comment: Your URL paramater also needs a "-"

Answer (score 1):

The deploy:deploy-file solution above still requires a settings.xml file. The login credentials will be retrieved from the setting.xml "servers" section using the ID specified in the repositoryId parameter.  There isn't any way that I know of to deploy using Maven without a settings.xml file. But you can specify a custom settings.xml file with "mvn -s some/path/settings.xml".

Alternatively, you could use a Jenkins plugin to do the deploy:  https://help.sonatype.com/integrations/nexus-and-continuous-integration/nexus-platform-plugin-for-jenkins#NexusPlatformPluginforJenkins-RepositoryManager3Integration