# mvn deploy specific url

Tags: maven, nexus

Trying to deploy an artifact to nexus, but it has to be in a specific location which ignores the groupId. Is there a way to do this?

```
<groupId>com.company.team</groupId>
<artifactId>project</artifactId>
<version>0.0.3-SNAPSHOT</version>
```

the url for our internal repository is:

http://repo.com/teamRepo/somedir/artifact/version/

but maven deploy (as expected) uploads to:

http://repo.com/teamRepo/com/company/team/artifact/version/

Comment: Have you configured your distributionManagement correctly?

Comment: Are you using Nexus/Artifactory? Why do you want to eliminate the groupId?

Comment: We're using nexus, it's not my decision unfortunately, the testing teams expect a tar in a certain location

Answer (score 0):

Was able to do this by using the mvn deploy:deploy-file command:

```
 mvn deploy:deploy-file -Durl=https://repo.com/teamRepo -DgroupId=team -DartifactId=artifact -Dversion=0.0.3 -Dpackaging=tar.gz -DskipTests -Dmaven.install.skip=true -DrepositoryId=repoId -Dfile=target/artifact.tar.gz
```

using -DrepositoryId was to allow the use of credentials stored as per this answer [Maven: Trying to Deploy with credentials in settings.xml file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12040566/maven-trying-to-deploy-with-credentials-in-settings-xml-file)